# Trying to make my site responsive on all devices especially on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my site responsive on all devices especially on mobile phones but I cannot figure out how to make it. I had tried different break points also but it doesn't work. Suggest me some way  to make it responsive.

Comment: Try to make as much as possible defined in relative units e.g. % and vmin rather than fixed px. You may need to involve px when sizing something the user has to read or touch - e.g. as a minimum size for a font or a button's dimensions - but otherwise if you can make things relative to the viewport things automatically become pretty responsive. Of course there will come a time when you'll want to have a different design for a very narrow device versus a very wide one and for that use media queries e.g. to go from a grid with 4 columns down to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` should help add some scaling fixes.

Answer (score -1):

You have many ways, two of them are :

Option 1: Pure CSS

By using `@media` you can determine browser size and write different CSS for different browser sizes

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
   Selector{
       Prop: Value;
   }
}
```

Option 2:

You can use a responsive CSS library like Bootstrap and use its grid layout,

BS Considers every container element like every division as 12 columns and you can set different columns for different devices

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6" ></div>
```

For example in this short code, i said my division should take all 12 possible columns of Bootstrap, BUT, it should take only 6 columns(half of the page) in medium devices (md)
Which in bs(up to Version 5) are devices larger than 768px